# Tensorflow : ValueError: Dimensions must be equal

Tags: python, tensorflow

I ran the code of that [tutorial](https://medium.com/@Currie32/predicting-movie-review-sentiment-with-tensorflow-and-tensorboard-53bf16af0acf) and I got the following error

I read some similar posts but it didn't really help me

> ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 128 and 364 for
>   'RNN_forward/rnn/while/rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/basic_lstm_cell/MatMul_1' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [250,128], [364,256].

Here is the code at the end of the tutorial :

```
n_words = len(word_index)
embed_size = 300
batch_size = 250
lstm_size = 128
num_layers = 2
dropout = 0.5
learning_rate = 0.001
epochs = 100
multiple_fc = False
fc_units = 256


# Train the model with the desired tuning parameters# Train  
for lstm_size in [64,128]:
    for multiple_fc in [True, False]:
        for fc_units in [128, 256]:
            log_string = 'ru={},fcl={},fcu={}'.format(lstm_size,
                                                      multiple_fc,
                                                      fc_units)
            model = build_rnn(n_words = n_words, 
                              embed_size = embed_size,
                              batch_size = batch_size,
                              lstm_size = lstm_size,
                              num_layers = num_layers,
                              dropout = dropout,
                              learning_rate = learning_rate,
                              multiple_fc = multiple_fc,
                              fc_units = fc_units)            
            train(model, epochs, log_string)
```

I changed the dataset on which the analysis is applied and I tried to adapt it.
Do you have an idea how I could solve that error ?

I read some similar posts but it didn't really help me.

Thank you very much

Comment: could you print n_words value too please

Comment: n_words value is 5971

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going through the link of the tutorial, i found this [link of the same issue](https://github.com/Currie32/Movie-Reviews-Sentiment/issues/2).

It suggests to merge ur code with [this repository](https://github.com/Gabfranck/Movie-Reviews-Sentiment/tree/patch-1) .

Give it a try and let me know if it fixes the issue :)

Comment: Thanks :) , I'll try that

Comment: Thank you very much Krishna , it helped me a lot :)

Comment: Glad to know that. Will u pls mark my answer as 'accepted' if it helped u.. (and upvote too if u liked it) :)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem thanks to that [post](https://github.com/Currie32/Movie-Reviews-Sentiment/issues/1) , I replaced this code :

```
  with tf.name_scope('RNN_layers'):
   lstm = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(lstm_size)
   drop = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(lstm, output_keep_prob=keep_prob)
   cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([drop] * num_layers)
```

by that code :

```
with tf.name_scope('RNN_layers'):
 cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([lstm_cell(lstm_size, keep_prob) for _ in 
 range(num_layers)])
```

by adding the following function also :

```
 def lstm_cell(lstm_size, keep_prob):
    lstm = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(lstm_size)
    drop = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(lstm, output_keep_prob=keep_prob)
    return drop
```